# Remove characters before character “|”

Tags: c#

I have a software which needs to remove all of the characters before "|".
For example input

" text needs to removed | Text needs to stay "

An example output will be

"Text needs to stay"

I have the code down below. It works for single-line text but doesn't work on multiple lines. (only removes the text on the first line rest of them stays the same)

I need to make it work with multiple lines. Any ideas?

```
 string input = richTextBox.Text;

  
  
 string output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('|') + 1);

 richTextBox1.Text = output;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it easily using the Lines property and a temporary `List<string>` to store the result of substring

```
List<string> newLines = new List<string>();
foreach (string s in richTextBox1.Lines)
{
    // If you want only the lines with the | remove the else block
    int x = s.IndexOf('|');
    if(x > -1)
        newLines.Add(s.Substring(x + 1).Trim());
    else
        newLines.Add(s);
}
richTextBox1.Lines = newLines.ToArray();
```

Comment: You may want to set the initial capacity of the List to the number of lines. You'd have to store Lines in a temporary first though to prevent the getter's splitting logic

Answer (score 0):

```
string output = "";        
var myArray = input.Split("\r\n");
        
        foreach(var ar in myArray)
            if(ar.Length > 0)
             output+= ar.Substring(0, ar.IndexOf('|')) + "\r\n";
```

Oups! i returned the first part, but i suppose you got the point

Comment: This assumes it's guaranteed all lines will have a pipe. It also returns the first part of each line, not the second. Also a string builder is probably better in this case (though depends on overall length I suppose)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 That's true, although the question itself is a bit generic. On the second part, what kind of software would load such amount of string in a richtextbox? I guess proposing using an stringbuilder in a simple as 123 question would be too much. For this reason i also kept my answer as simple as i could

Answer (score 0):

What about using LINQ for this.
E.g.:

```
List<string> lines = yourString.Split("\n"); //Add \r if needed
List<string> smallerLines = lines.Select(x => x.Skip(x.IndexOf('|')+1));
```

If needed you can always create one new string of the output:

```
string finalString = String.Join(String.Empty, smallerLines);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         string input = richTextBox1.Text;
>         int len = richTextBox1.Lines.Length;
>         string output = "";
>  
>         for (int i = 0; i <len; i++)
>         { 
>             if(i!=len-1)
>             {
>                 output += richTextBox1.Lines[i].Substring(input.IndexOf('|') + 1) +
>                 Environment.NewLine;
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 output += richTextBox1.Lines[i].Substring(input.IndexOf('|') + 1);
>             }
>
>             
>         }
>         richTextBox1.Text = output;
> ```